# Unable to handle click events in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, event-handling

The button I am trying to handle:

```
< input type="submit" class="btn FlowNextBtn" value="Next" name="p:i:f:bottom:next" id="p:i:f:bottom:next">
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
$(".FlowNextBtn").click(function() {
    alert("Clicked");
});
```

and

```
$("[id='p:i:f:bottom:next']").click(function() {
    alert("Clicked");
});
```

and

```
$("[id='p:i:f:bottom:next']").one("click", function() {
    alert("Clicked");
});
```

and

```
document.getElementById("p:i:f:bottom:next").addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("Clicked");
});
```

and

```
document.getElementById("p:i:f:bottom:next").onclick = function() {
    alert("Clicked");
};
```

All of the above work fine in Chrome; when the button is clicked I get the alert popup. Any ideas what's causing Firefox to dislike the script? I'm not even seeing any errors in the Firebug console. When I debug the objects that I get using JS/jQuery I always see something in the console (i.e. the script is finding the button but it's not able to handle the click event).

Comment: The `submit` buttons make a request with the info from the parent form, try changing the  `type` to `button`.

Comment: Try removing the empty space before input and close the input control tag. <input type="submit" class="btn FlowNextBtn" value="Next" name="p:i:f:bottom:next" id="p:i:f:bottom:next"/>.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded Firefox and this issue went away! It was on version 19.0.